# activate_page doesn't work in intelXDK

Tags: javascript, cordova, events, mobile, intel-xdk

I'm building an mobile app using IntelXDK. I want to switch page (it has different layout than current one) and I want to use `activate_page` method.

If I enter it through "design view" it works fine, but when I copypaste it to my custom event I've got an error:

```
'activate_page' is not defined. (W117)
```

What I'm doing wrong? Please help.

This is my code, everything works fine till the last code line:

```
$("#product-list").on("click", "li a", function(evt)
{
  /* your code goes here */ 
  productId = $(this).data('id'); //this is variable defined in outer scope - not important right now
  showProduct(productId); // this is my other custom function which works - not important right now
  activate_page("#product-details-view");  //this line doesn't work - very important right now ;)
});
```

To answer futere questions - yes, I have `product-details-view` page.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `acivate_page` is a function internal to AppDesigner, which may no longer be used.  There is an `activate_subpage` which works for me, but again that's an internal AD function.  Instead you should use the appropriate call for the framework you're using.  For example, if you're using App Framework you would call `loadContent`, i.e.

```
af.ui.loadContent("#product-details-view");
```

This would be the more appropriate (and safer) thing to do, as internal functions could change in lots of different ways.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jshint global directive before calling activate_page:

```
/* global activate_page */
activate_page("#product-details-view");
```

or you can configure it manually using a jshint resource file.

See http://www.jshint.com/docs/ for more information regarding jshint.